# Google Tag Manager: Google Analytics script is only loaded if i override the Analytics ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having problems getting my Google Analytics tags to fire correctly. 
I'm using the **Google Analytics Settings** variable type, but my tags don't fire unless I override the Analytics ID on my tags, and it's just a pain.

Here's what I have done:

1. I have created a **Google Analytics Settings** variable and set it up with my Analytics tracking ID (I've made sure there are no whitespaces around it the id) 
   [image]
2. I have created a Google Analytics tag and referenced my settings variable like this.
   [image]

Now when i visit my webpage with the GTM script and fire the related trigger, nothing happens.

**But** if I override the tracking ID with the same value that is used in my Google Analytics Settings variable like this:
[image]
and fire the same trigger as before, my tag fires just fine, and my events are tracked.

The text says "Inherited from settings variable", so I'd expect everything to work without overriding anything.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I think your actual GA variable is `{{CONST - Analytics ID}}` instead of the other one.
In your case use `{{CONST - Analytics ID}}` instead of `{{Google Analytics - Basic settings}}`.